# Single selection CheckedListBox control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a [CheckedListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx) control.I want to limit it's selection property to one means now a user can select more than one item in the control, need to limit this property to single selection only.

For example, Let's `CHKListsolutions` has following items

```
Google
Bing
Yahoo
```

Normally we can select 3 of them because of an obvious reason.
How to make this CHKListsolutions to select only one item in the list.

for example, I select Google and for some reason I want chnage the selection so I will select Yahoo  then my last selection should unchecked and new one should be checked

I have checked in the resource for a property but in vain.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: winforms? web? wpf?

Comment: uisng in winforms

Comment: Did you consider using `RadioButton`s instead of `CheckedListBox`? They perfectly meet the described requirement out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Private Sub CHKListsolutions_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles CHKListsolutions.MouseClick
        Dim  idx, sidx As Integer
        sidx = CHKListsolutions.SelectedIndex
        For idx = 0 To CHKListsolutions.Items.Count - 1
            If idx <> sidx Then
                CHKListsolutions.SetItemChecked(idx, False)
            Else
                CHKListsolutions.SetItemChecked(sidx, True)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

In MouseClick event you'll get the currently selected index of the item in the control(`sidx`) use this `sidx` to loop through number of items in the control and uncheck checked item that is not equal to the current index using [SetItemChecked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked(v=vs.110).aspx) method

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Radio Button instead of Checkedlistbox

Comment: Another user commented this on the question.  OP might gain benefit from an example code snippet, in the event they haven't used radio buttons, or are just starting out.